# Is it true that CPU never fetches anything from memory directly?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I hear that cpu just fetches instruction from the `EIP` register,never fetches from memory directly.

But AFAIK,`EIP` just stores the **address** of the next instruction,the instruction itself is still in the memory.If CPU never fetches memory,how can it know what the next instruction actually is?

**UPDATE**

BTW,I know there're x86,x64,x87 architectures,but which does `x86-64` belong to,`x86` or `x64`??

Comment: x86-64 belongs to x64 (but differen vendors have differing architectures)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is "no, it's not true".

The picture isn't very simple due to caching, instruction pipeline, branch prediction etc. However, the instruction pointer is just that, a pointer. It doesn't store opcodes.

Answer (score 2):

EIP (Extended Instruction Pointer) should hold the address of the instruction. It's just a way to keep a tab of which instruction is being processed currently (or sometimes, which instruction to process next).

The instructions themselves are stored in the Memory (HDD, RAM, Cache) and need to be fetched by the CPU.

Maybe what you heard meant that since so many levels of caches are used generally it's quite rare that the fetch needs to access the RAM..

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know the point to your question.

Yes the CPU (in a broad sense of the word) does fetch from memory. It has a number of memory management devices (for cache line handling and pipelining). In fact, the 'pipeline' puts the instructions in L1 cache. Indeed, the instruction processor itself only fetches from there. The processor in reality probably never even looks at EIP (unless an instruction uses it directly as an operand).

So the real answer would be, find yourself a wikipedia articale on i86 processor design, and have a ball. You'll be able to know exactly what happens where.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not true in that way. CPU accesses memory thru the cache, so you can kinda say that it does not do it directly. (Also DMA cahnnel can transfer data between memory and IO without ever touching CPU).

Yes, CS:EIP points to the memory, to the next instruction to execute, but you can use direct addresses too for example (load the content of the address 0x0800 to the AX register, by default this is relative to DS segment):

```
MOV AX,[0x0800]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how CPU accesses memory thru the cache?

Comment: `you can use direct addresses too` - does this have any relevance to the question? There are a lot of other instructions and addressing modes that are left in the cold there

Comment: @compile-fan: let's not for a moment? There is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache to get you started

Comment: @sehe I tried to emphesize that you don't even need to use the special pointer registers (EIP, ESP, EBP stc) to access memory. I also refined my example a bit.

Comment: @compile-fan The cache works pretty autonomously, you don't have to worry about it even when you code in ASM. The Wikipedia article is pretty exhaustive about it.